# iPhone Choking on Certain Image Formats

Tags: iphone, quartz-graphics

My app allows upload of an image from the camera roll.  Some images are causing the app to crash when I attempt to save them to my documents directory prior to upload.  I'm converting the image to a PNG prior to saving, but that hasn't helped.  Here's the error...

```
Tue Aug 31 20:39:13 localhost XXX[76409] <Error>: CGBitmapContextCreate: unsupported parameter combination: 8 integer bits/component; 32 bits/pixel; 3-component color space; kCGImageAlphaLast; 1600 bytes/row.
Tue Aug 31 20:39:13 localhost XXX[76409] <Error>: CGContextConcatCTM: invalid context 0x0
Tue Aug 31 20:39:13 localhost XXX[76409] <Error>: CGContextSetInterpolationQuality: invalid context 0x0
Tue Aug 31 20:39:13 localhost XXX[76409] <Error>: CGContextDrawImage: invalid context 0x0
Tue Aug 31 20:39:13 localhost XXX[76409] <Error>: CGBitmapContextCreateImage: invalid context 0x0
```

and here's a sample of my code...

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

            UIImage *img =  [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];

        NSData *pngData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img);

        UIImage *pngImg = [UIImage imageWithData:pngData];

... code to save image ...

}
```

Comment: You should provide the code nearby where the crash happens. The errors that you are getting only say that you are using a invalid context to manipulate your image.

Answer (score 0):

Note also that what you are doing is redundant and a waste of memory. `img` and `pngImg` are the same. Or is there a specific reason that you convert an image to png and then back to an image?